# Instrumentation using gradle on Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, activejdbc, javalite

i am using ActiveJDBC for my Android App, and Im having trouble on instrumentation.

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.javalite.activejdbc'

buildscript {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      mavenCentral()
      maven {url 'http://repo.javalite.io'}
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
      classpath group: 'org.javalite', name: 'activejdbc-gradle-plugin', version: '2.0'
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      mavenCentral()
      maven {url 'http://repo.javalite.io'}
   }
}

dependencies {
//   compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.25'
     compile group: 'org.javalite', name: 'activejdbc', version: '2.0'
     compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.5'
     testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

task run(dependsOn: 'build', type: JavaExec) {
     main = 'ph.com.partnersolutions.activejdbforandroidtest.MainActivity'
     classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But this doesn't work. Am i doing it right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing any information on what is not working. However, you are using a JavaLite released version 2.0 and also using the outdated  SNAPSHOT  repo http://repo.javalite.io which you do not need. I suggest you switch to latest version 2.2 and remove the repo http://repo.javalite.io because it is not available anymore. Months ago we switched to Sonatype as most Java projects. You can find the info here: 
http://javalite.io/releases#current-snapshot-2.3-snapshot

Also, please check out the working Gradle example: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc-gradle

EDIT July 11 2019: 
Please, see an official Gradle Plugin: https://github.com/cschabl/activejdbc-gradle-plugin

Comment: The instrumentation doesn't work. I followed the Gradle example which looks easy but I still got the error that says "> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\vadin\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJDBC\build\classes\java\main\activejdbc_models.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)", I already applied your update too, but this error still exist.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your project, but I developed a Gradle sample that works. You need to see what is wrong with your config. The directory C:\Users\vadin\AndroidStudioProjects\TestJDBC\build\classes\java\main\ is strange, maybe it is a place to look

Answer (score 0):

`build\classes\<jvm-language>\main\` is the new directory layout for JVM-language plugins since Gradle 4. The Gradle plugin of ActiveJDBC 2.2 knows about this and adjusts the classes dir dependending on the Gradle version.

You can also try the new [ActiveJDBC Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/de.schablinski.activejdbc-gradle-plugin).

Comment: @vincent-dingding, what Gradle version do you use and which Gradle command did you execute? (I'm commenting on my own answer, because of missing reputation I couldn't comment on your question)